# Is there a way to optimize this glsl?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

There is textures array (uSamplerArr), textures coordinates bias(texBiasArr), opacity(alfaArr) and transparent colors array(tcolorArr).

In result - low framerate.

How to optimize this shader?

Vertex shader

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

uniform mat4 uPMVMatrix;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {

  gl_Position = uPMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}
```

Fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;
precision lowp int;

const int MAX_TEX = 8;
const float COLOR_DIFF_EPS = 0.4;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform int numTex;
uniform sampler2D uSamplerArr[MAX_TEX];
uniform float alfaArr[MAX_TEX];
uniform vec3 tcolorArr[MAX_TEX];
uniform vec3 texBiasArr[MAX_TEX];

void main(void) 
{
  vec4 res = texture2D(uSamplerArr[0], texBiasArr[0].z * (vTextureCoord + vec2(texBiasArr[0].x,     texBiasArr[0].y)));

  if(numTex > 1)
  {
    vec4 ti;
    for( int i = 1; i < MAX_TEX; i++ ) 
    {
      if( i < numTex ) 
      {
        ti = texture2D(uSamplerArr[i], texBiasArr[i].z * (vTextureCoord + texBiasArr[i].xy));

        if( length( ti.rgb - tcolorArr[i] ) > COLOR_DIFF_EPS ) 
        {
          res = mix(res, ti, alfaArr[i]);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  gl_FragColor = res;
}
```

Comment: I would start by commenting out sections of your shader until you can nail down what portion is causing the slowdown...

Comment: Change `vec2(texBiasArr[0].x, texBiasArr[0].y)` to just `texBiasArr[0].xy` and for loop to `for(int i=1; i<numTex; i++)`.

Comment: Dependent texture reads may be a problem on some hardware (especially mobile). Try hoisting the texture coordinate calculation into the vertex shader.